# How to build an executable jar for a gradle spring-boot project

Tags: spring, gradle

I am new to spring-boot and gradle.

The following simple project was running fine in Eclipse(Kepler) IDE. I tried to publish it with a stand alone fatjar and got run time errors.

Here is run time errors I got:

```
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Jan 05, 2015 6:22:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52
Jan 05, 2015 6:22:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
18:22:41.018 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5927 ms
Jan 05, 2015 6:22:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:799)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.servlet.Filter org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity.authorizeRequests()Lorg/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer$ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry;
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:597)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:989)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getOrderedBeansOfType(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:367)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:268)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:213)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.ServletContextInitializerLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(ServletContextInitializerLifecycleListener.java:54)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5355)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.servlet.Filter org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity.authorizeRequests()Lorg/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer$ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry;
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:188)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:586)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity.authorizeRequests()Lorg/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer$ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry;
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration$ApplicationWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.configure(SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration.java:206)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:159)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:247)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration$ApplicationWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7a10239e.init()
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:352)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:305)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:40)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:85)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c5e616ce.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$1()
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c5e616ce$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9dcff015.invoke()
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c5e616ce.springSecurityFilterChain()
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
        ... 23 more

Jan 05, 2015 6:22:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:341)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:79)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:69)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:270)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:145)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:159)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:132)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:648)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:909)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:898)
        at jimpath.com.Application.main(Application.java:46)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:799)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 6 more

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:135)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:648)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:909)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:898)
        at jimpath.com.Application.main(Application.java:46)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:106)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:69)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:270)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:145)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:159)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:132)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:341)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:79)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 18 more
```

Here is my code link:
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B8rGCG6G38SqUHdqRXNsSVlRQ2M&usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I commented out 
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
in build.gradle, and then built with gradle out of Eclipse with gradle wrapper. it works!